# Upload files in Apache WebServer (Windows 10)

Tags: apache-http-server

I have succesfully installed Apache WebServer on my Windows 10 pc.

I am trying to upload some files in it, but couldn't find way. It's ridiculous the amount of misleading information you find online about this specific topic.

So I am asking you: ***is there a way to have a sort of "file system" on apache webserver where I can Upload some files (images, text, whatever) ?***
If not, is there a component, module or whatever it is to make it happen ?
My plan is to use Apache NiFi (installed in a remote server) to get the files from the Apache web server (installed on local) and build a dataflow pipeline which will move / copy the file to a destination db (hadoop probably).
Setting up an Apache Webserver in order to mess around with Apache NiFi dataflows has been suggested to me by a senior dev colleague. Does he even know what he is talking about ?

When I access the Webserver by typing down the ip (127.0.0.1) the only thing I can see is "index of /" (I removed the Index page) and nothing else. No dir, files or whatever.

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent FTP ?

Comment: FTP (not part of Apache httpd) is the standard.  Have you looked into Webdav? (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-webdav-access-with-apache-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: Alternatively there are a plethora of php based file managers which might do you.

Comment: Uploading files is something the most basic server administrator learns how to do. The method used depends. Are you uploading files to the server as an administrator? Are you uploading files as part of a client application? The correct relevant details matter to get good answers. Edit your post and clarify your problem.